# How to enable find-as-you-type behavior?

Tags: midnight-commander

Ok, I just need Total Commander 'quick search' feature to be enabled. How can I do it?

Answer (score 35):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
[will show the "quick search"](https://midnight-commander.org/wiki/doc/common/actions) in Midnight Commander.

Comment: Thanks! Can I turn this on by default (so I won't need to press extra Alt-S to begin searhing and maybe another key combiantion to focus on command line)?

Comment: Glad it helped you out, i don't have a clue on how to enable it by default though.

Comment: Is there a way to make this case insensitive?

Comment: In case anyone gets here misremembering `Alt`+`S` for `Ctrl`+`S`: [hit `Ctrl`+`Q` to unfreeze the terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137842/what-is-the-point-of-ctrl-s)...

Comment: @Gaurav I'm 4 years late, but you can set case sensivity in Options -> Panel options -> Quick search -> Case insensitive

Answer (score 33):

Go to Options > Layout and disable Command prompt. You'll get the desired behavior.

Comment: Awesome. Unfortunately it only searches the beginning of the name.

Comment: What I really want is this behavior, but in addition pressing Arrow right to enter shell mode. It's like this in Total Commander on windows.

Comment: @TheStoryCoder if you use "*" as the first character in the search, it will also search within names :-)

Comment: @Regisz Oh nice, didn't even think of that. If I only press * as the beginning character though it will just select all my files, but if I press space and then * it works :)

Comment: @TheStoryCoder cool :-)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was options >> Quick Search >> select Letter Only.  >Ok

Such a help.

Comment: Welcome to the community. This is a 12 years old posting, and TC has been in active development, so it's quite possible the behavior and locations of options have changed. Add the TC version and screenshots to improve the answer (it's flagged as low quality and likely to get deleted). I'd also suggest removing "Such a help" - SE communities aren't discussion boards, they work a bit differently. I'd suggest you take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and check the Asking and Answering -sections in [Help](https://superuser.com/help). That'll give you a good handle on how things work.